# Multiselect option edit on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiselect menu. I want a user to be able to edit an option on double click.

The jquery code seems to work fine on anything except  tags within a multi select. I attempted using  to do it with no avail. Every time a user enters a letter, the multiselect does its native property of automatically selecting the first option in the list whose first few letters are what the user typed in.

```js
$(".editable").dblclick(function (e) {
    if ($(event.target).attr('class') != "thVal")
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        updateVal(currentEle, value);
    }
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value)
{
    $(document).off('click');
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

        $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
    }
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" class="form-control" size = 3>
  <option class="editable">1</option>
  <option class="editable">2</option>
  <option class="editable">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think click events are valid on the `option` tag, only on the parent `select` tag. But to still achieve editing the options, you could wrap each select within a div, that contains an "edit" button, and target the option tags by their indexes to change them.

Comment: You can't put `<input>`s inside `<option>` elements. Only text is allowed.

Comment: How about contenteditable="true"? It didnt look like it worked with me, but i was wondering if thats a work around